# ASP.NET Mvc Button in jumbotron can't be moved up

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've tried margin-bottom, padding, top:5px; but nothing seems to be moving it.

`<p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" margin-bottom:10px; style='float:right;'  >Find out more! &raquo;</a></p>`

[image: Anyone know how to fix this? Bootstrap.]

css contains too many stuff for me to find the css I need to change. Is there anyway I can change it from my Index view?

Comment: It would be helpful if you more clearly stated what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `padding-bottom` to a higher value in the `jumbotron` class. If you post your code or css it will be easier to identify the problem and help you.

Answer (score 0):

open developer tools from your browser, "Press F12 in case of Chrome", Click on the "Select an element from page to view it" as marked in picture, then in right corner as marked RED, change CSS code and view its effect, after successful change, copy that code and paste in your custom css file, and add it at the last of included CSS files, as last added CSS file has the highest priority in order of execution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

margin-top:-5px should work. You can also position the anchor element via position: relative and bottom:5px